# Understanding useRef and useEffect in this general example

Tags: javascript, reactjs

So I am trying to understand useRef properly but there is one thing I am unable to wrap my head around. See this basic example

```
function App() {
    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(0);
    const previousCountRef = useRef(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        previousCountRef.current = counter
    },[counter]) 

    return(
        <>
        <h1>{counter}</h1>
        {previousCountRef.current !== null && (<h5>Prev: 
        {previousCountRef.current}</h5>)}  // check if previous is not null

    <button onClick={() => setCounter(counter + 1)}>CLICKME</button>
    )
    </>

}
```

So in this example, we increment the counter by 1 if we press the button. our useEffect only updates if we change the value of counter. Our ref variable is able to store the value of counter before it is changed.

That is the part that confuses me. How is the useEffect able to store the value of the previous counter? If we click the button, the counter is updated. Because the counter is updated, useEffect can run and gets set equal to the value of counter. How is the ref variable 1 step behind?

On initial render, the counter variable changes from null to 0 so it runs useEffect in that situation as well, thereby setting prevCountRef.current = 0 too. They are in sync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer is two parts:

1. `useEffect` runs *after* the render. So this code `previousCountRef.current = counter` runs after the `setCounter` has completed and the component has re-rendered.
2. Updating refs does not cause re-renders. So the code `previousCountRef.current = counter` does not trigger a re-render for you to see the new value in your JSX.

This leads to the ref printing one step behind, even though its actual current value may have already been updated to match the state.

Comment: This makes sense. So the logic here is that when the function first runs, its sets the state to 0, then renders the component, then runs the use effect. This is why when the component renders, previousCountRef.current is null at the time of rendering and fails the boolean check to display the previous count. Then onClick counter goes to 1, re-renders bc counter state change, then since previousCountRef.current has a value of 0 (not null) from the previous useEffect, it passes the boolean check to display <h5/>.  After this renders, the ref is then set to 1. 

Thanks so much